# Magento 2 Marketplace and Semantic Versioning

Tags: magento2, marketplace, semantic-versioning

For folks who've purchased and downloaded extensions from Magento Marketplace, are the module's there using semantic versioning?  i.e. -- do the third party modules have a `require` section in their `composer.json` files that lists out the Magento components the third party module needs in order to work correctly?

I realize this is going to vary by vendor, but I'm trying to get a feel for how widely used the feature is.

Comment: Of the three vendors I've used on my current project (Unirgy, Xtento [the only one through Marketplace], Fooman) only Fooman has instructions for composer - and involves a zip file into the vendor directory.  None mention SemVer as far as I've seen.

Comment: Actually, lots of developers do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the answer to this one was "no, most extension vendors are not using the semantic versioning system".